# In Ember, how do I transmute sticky query parameters a user enters?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Fairly new to Ember so I apologize if I'm using the wrong terminology here.  I have a form with sticky parameters that's binding a user modifying that form to the URL also changing, but I'd like to run an additional transformation (for example, hashing that value), but I'm not sure how to hook into this behavior.

My initial reaction was to hook into didTransition as it looks like this fires every time the form is modified, but it doesn't look like didTransition has access to the query parameters.  I'd appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

If (as it sounds like) you're wanting to adjust the URL, you can use serialize/ deserialize hooks for each route to make the changes you are after: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize